# What elements does jQuery serialize affect?

Tags: jquery, serialization

I'm digging through the jquery production file and it doesn't seem that there's a definitive list of elements jquery will serialize. IE how does it know to serialize inputs and selects? I am curious because I have a common function to serialize my forms, that first does some checkbox value conversions among other things. The next thing I wanted it to do is ignore all form inputs/selects that have the class "fake"

```
var postData = form.find('input, select').not('.fake').serialize();
```

This actually works great but I am worried that there are more form elements I am not thinking of that are serializable, and that I will have an issue in the future. I cannot currently think of any other elements, and perhaps there will be some added in the future.

Is there a better way to future-proof this?

Comment: When in doubt, read the docs: `The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form controls, such as <input>, <textarea>, and <select>: $( "input, textarea, select" ).serialize();` http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: It says 'such as', though.

Comment: [I recommend reading the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/serialize.js).

Comment: There are other `form` related elements, such as `fieldset` and `button`, but those listed in the jQuery snippet are the only ones which will have a value which will be sent in a request.

Comment: Talking in jQuery, all elements which you need to use `.val()` instead of  `.text()` to get its values 

Comment: @zzzzBov  Literally the first thing I said is I am reading the source. If YOU can see without a doubt what exact elements are accounted for, I will be surprised. The closest thing I see is    var elements = jQuery.prop( this, "elements" );  and even then it's not clear what "elements" refers to.

Comment: you said "I'm digging through the jquery production file", which tells me you're looking at a larger compiled version, rather than examining just the module in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Serialized Elements

jQuery currently (1.11.3) checks for `input`, `select`, `textarea`, and `keygen` elements.

<sub>[serialize.js line 13](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/serialize.js):</sub>

```
rsubmittable = /^(?:input|select|textarea|keygen)/i;
```

This gets used on lines 93-100 when filtering which elements to serialize:

```
.filter(function() {
    var type = this.type;

    // Use .is( ":disabled" ) so that fieldset[disabled] works
    return this.name && !jQuery( this ).is( ":disabled" ) &&
        rsubmittable.test( this.nodeName ) && !rsubmitterTypes.test( type ) &&
        ( this.checked || !rcheckableType.test( type ) );
})
```

### Future Proofing

As far as "future proofing" is concerned, you'll always be stuck with whatever your current version of jQuery handles. The easiest way to make sure that your script is selecting the same elements as jQuery is to serialize the form rather than the collection of elements:

```
$('.the-form').serialize();
```

Of course, that won't filter out any of the "fake" input, but from the snippet of code above it's clear that disabled elements aren't included in the serialization. The trick is to just disable any fake elements that aren't already disabled, and then re-enable them after serialization is complete:

```
var $fakes = $('.fake:not(:disabled)').prop('disabled', true);
var serialization = $('.the-form').serialize();
$fakes.prop('disabled', false);
```